# add new items to repeater on textchanged event using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to develop a small POS web application using asp.net c#, I have created a textbox for barcode scanning like all POS software do, I would like to have the repeater which shows the customer's items being scanned, to update; adding new rows with each scan.

So far I have created a `List<>` object and I am trying to use the `List.Add()` method to append new rows on finding scanned item in the database, but the `databind()` method always returns the last item scanned; this looks normal to me so I am basically doing something wrong.

Can anyone help or the repeater is not capable of this. See code below; I was assuming adding to the list will append and keep the list growing since `List<>` is defined at the top class level.

```
public partial class POS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    rocketEntities2 posx = new rocketEntities2();
    List<item> holdall = new List<item>();
    String hold = "";
    int i = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var prev = posx.items.OrderByDescending(x=>x.NumberOfSales).Take(200);
        var take = from x in posx.items
                   where x.Name != null
                   orderby x.Name descending
                   select new { itemName = x.Name, itemCode = x.Barcode, itemPrice = x.Selling, itemQty = x.CurrentQuantity };

        //var prev = posx.items.Select(x=>x.Name != null);
        GridView1.DataSource = take.ToList().Take(100);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void scan_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //IQueryable<item> selected;
        if (posx.items.Any(x => x.Barcode == scan.Text))
        {
            var take = (posx.items.Single(x => x.Barcode == scan.Text));
            holdall.Add(take);
            // hold += take.Name + "," + take.Selling + "\n";
            Repeater1.DataSource = holdall;
            positemlist.Text = hold += take.Name + "," + take.Selling + "\n";
        }
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```